# CSS Grid full width columns on the mobile

Tags: css, css-grid

I use CSS Grid to show 2 columns (50% grey/50% black). You see how it looks
[image]

I want to make them full width on the mobile, so that gray would be in the first line, and black one in the second line.

My CSS:

```
.container {
display:grid;
height:100vh;
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(50%, 1fr))
}
```

What I am doing wrong?

**P.S. I know all things can be done with @media queries, but I need more modern way.**

Comment: Apart from [container queries](https://caniuse.com/css-container-queries) there's nothing much more modern than media queries.

Comment: But... Is the principle of Grid is not to change media queries?

Comment: Could you rephrase? I don't quite know what your question is?

Comment: check this: https://css-tricks.com/responsive-layouts-fewer-media-queries/

Comment: Powerful stuff; I wonder how to integrate with Tailwind, to use it's breakpoints rather than defining manual breakpoint vars.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be solved without media queries as you requested: You just need to use `flex` instead of `grid`.

Here's an example:

```
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-container .flex-item {
    flex:max(500px, 100% / 3);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item" style="background-color: gray"></div>
  <div class="flex-item" style="background-color: black"></div>
</div>
```

With this code, we specify that it be deployed as the `flex` type, and then we establish that it can be a multiline container with `wrap`.

The elements inside the container with the `flex:max(500px, 100% / 3)` property will be displayed split unless the width of the elements inside the flex container is less than 500px.

If you want to increase the number of maximum columns, you can do it like this:

```
flex:max(500px, 100% / 3) // 2 columns
flex:max(500px, 100% / 4) // 3 columns
flex:max(500px, 100% / 5) // 4 columns
...
```